# How can i vieuw two MS Excel files(on 2 screens) at the same time?

Tags: excel

Im working with MS Excel files and need to copy/transfer pars from one excel file to an other. (I know it is possible to copy sheets... but there has to be a better solution)

I'm working with multiple monitors/screens to display MS Excel file. (but all on juist one Computer. But somehow i cant display two files at the same time.
Is there a way to solve this?
What is the reason this isn't possible? (is it because, in Excel VBA macro's there can only be one open workbook. to prevent you ending up accedently editting multiple excel files at the same time?)
I don't think so, because the shoeld both be able to be vieuwed at the same time... but i only need one to be selected to edit.

Specs:
 - Dell Workbook
 - Window 7 Professional
 - MS Excel (Office 2010)

Thanks in advance,

best regards, Cornelis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In excel 2010, each time the excel application is opened it can have many workbooks open.   See the max/min/restore buttons in the top right corner of the excel window.  There is one set for excel and another set for the active workbook.  Restore the workbook window and you will be able to arrange it and any other workbook that are open.

Note that you can copy sheets between any workbook open in the same iinstance of excel.

you can open excel more than once (ie opening many instances) and the workbooks open in each instance are treated differently than when they are all opened in one instance.

Comment: Did you find the above useful?  If so please flag as an answer.